# Executing list of IEnumerable queries

Tags: linq

I have multiple Link queries loading to a IEnumerable list

```
var queries = new List<IEnumerable<Customers>>();
queries.Add(from c in context.Customers where c.region = 'NE' select c);
queries.Add(from c in context.Customers where c.region = 'SW' select c); 

//want count of customers in those two regions
var result = queries.Sum(q => Count());
```

However it is returning a count of the queries (2), not count of the Customers.

How can execute the List of IEnumerable queries?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is at the last line:

```cs
q => Count()
```

Instead of actually counting the elements in a sequence, which would be `q => q.Count()`, you are calling a method `Count()` of either a current instance or the current class.

Actually, there is no need to do two separate queries. Instead, use a single query:

```cs
var query = from c
            in context.Customers
            where c.region = 'NE' || c.region = 'SW'
            select c;

var result = query.Count();
```

or, slightly shorter:

```cs
var result = context.Customers.Count(c => c.region = 'NE' || c.region = 'SW');
```